# Compare text files from more than 3 folders at the same time?

Tags: file-management, file-merging

Araxis Merge supports 3 folders and Beyond Compare 2, but are there any application that can support more than 3 folder comparison, for text files, at the same time?

Subfolders is already supported and is not this request. I would like all the different folders be checked with all other folders.

For example which of these 10 folders a file is identical (or near with whitespaces changed). Now I have to compare 1 folder with 9 others + next folder with 8 others, plus next folder with 7 others and so on making 9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=45 different folder checks which takes alot of time (and easy to miss something).

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.